# Is it possible to mix a type's fields into another type?

Tags: typescript

Is there a way to do something like this?

```
type Details = {
  name: string
}

type Customer = {
  id: string,
  ...Details
}
```

So Customer effectively becomes this:

```
type Customer = {
  id: string,
  name: string
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use an [intersection type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#intersection-types):

```
type Customer = Details & {
  id: string
}
```

From the docs (emphasis mine):

> An intersection type **combines multiple types into one**. This allows you
>   to add together existing types to get a single type that has all the
>   features you need.

Comment: Thanks, it is what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

**This can be done**, as shown in the answer `jonrsharpe` posted. You can also extend the type with an interface like this:

```
export type Details = {
  name: string;
};

export interface Customer extends Details {
  id: string;
}

const customer: Customer = {
  name: 'name',
  id: 'id'
};
```

Answer (score -1):

I recently had this issue and i had a slight different approach:

```
type Details = {
  name: string
}

type Customer = {
  id: string,
  name: Details
}
```

It's not quite what you're looking for but it's one way of intersecting.